# Asterisk 13 " __set_address_from_contact: Invalid contact uri" error

Tags: asterisk

I'm installing Asterisk 13 on our production Ubuntu 14.0.4 box and the process seemed to go well.  I previously installed it on my personal server as well.  It works perfectly on my personal server, but on the production server, I periodically get this error:

```
[May 11 17:48:43] WARNING[6754]: chan_sip.c:16110 __set_address_from_contact: Invalid contact uri  (missing sip: or sips:), attempting to use anyway
[May 11 17:48:43] WARNING[6754]: chan_sip.c:16123 __set_address_from_contact: Invalid URI: parse_uri failed to acquire hostport
[May 11 17:48:43] WARNING[14673]: file.c:905 ast_readaudio_callback: Failed to write frame
[May 11 17:48:43] WARNING[14673]: app_playback.c:493 playback_exec: Playback failed on SIP/vitel-outbound-00000003 for tt-monkeys
```

To get the error, I'm running `asterisk -rvvvvv` and then running the command below to test:

```
channel originate SIP/vitel-outbound/15554443333 application Playback tt-monkeys
```

The first or second time I attempt the call, it works - my phone rings and I'm assaulted by monkey screams.  Usually the third or fourth time, however, I get the error shown above.  My phone does ring, but then it immediately hangs up when I answer.

If I exit asterisk and do a `sudo service asterisk restart`, everything goes back to being healthy for a few calls.

My only other observation is that in the failure cases, it tends to take a while before my phone rings.  When it works, I'll send the command and my phone will ring a few seconds later.

Any suggestions?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

1) is your production machine bare metal or Virtual - and in either case, do you have performance related timing delays, lag or other issues?  to Asterisk, timing can affect operations.

2) how far apart is the hang-up/redial actions?

3) does the problem go away if the hang-up and re-dial are separated by say one full minute?  If so investigate performance, resources, etc. on prod server.....

4) I assume your build steps were executed identically because they are written somewhere?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for helping.  Re 1) It's a virtual box spun up via Laravel Forge and DigitalOcean with no custom configuration beyond installing Asterisk 13 following http://www.mikeslab.net/?p=330.  I then updated sip.conf with a 'register' entry under OUTBOUND SIP REGISTRATIONS, and some specific credentials at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I can't find a clear pattern to the time issue.  When I run the test command, it takes about 5-10 seconds before my phone rings.  The time delay doesn't seem to be tied to the failure rate, though.  Sometimes it works when it takes 10+ seconds to connect, and sometimes it fails when it connects after 5 seconds.